# How can I input mouse buttons in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making a **Tic Tac Toe project** in c++ just for fun and I have done the part of making the gameboard.

I want to input where the user clicks so I can display the "Mark" Correctly. To test out my code I have tried  showing the number of the cell (1,2,3...). Whenever I click outside the board, it should show `-1`.

BUT INSTEAD it shows `-1` everywhere (in and out).

Below given is the part of my code which I wrote. The full code can be found on https://pastebin.com/dEQvRdhz

```
const int Cell_Size = 100;

BOOL GetBoard(HWND hwnd, RECT *pRect) {

    RECT rc;

    if (GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc)) {
        int *ptr;

        int width = rc.right - rc.left;
        int height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

        rc.left = (width - Cell_Size * 3) / 2;
        rc.top = (height - Cell_Size * 3) / 2;
        rc.right = (rc.left + Cell_Size * 3);
        rc.bottom = (rc.top + Cell_Size * 3);


        return TRUE;
    } SetRectEmpty(pRect);
    return FALSE;


}
int GetMousePoint(HWND hwnd,int x, int y)
{
    POINT pt = { x, y };


    RECT rc;
    if (GetBoard(hwnd,&rc )) 
    {
        if (PtInRect(&rc, pt)) 
        {
            x = pt.x - rc.left;
            y = pt.y - rc.top;

            int column = x / Cell_Size;
            int row = y / Cell_Size;

            return column+row;
        }   

    }return -1;
}

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

        {  
          int xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
            int yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);    
            int index = GetMousePoint(hWnd,xPos, yPos);

            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd); 
            if (NULL != hdc) {

                WCHAR temp[100];
                wsprintf(temp,L"Index = %d",index );
                TextOut(hdc, xPos, yPos, temp, lstrlen(temp));
                ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

            } 



        }

        break;

    case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:

        {
            MINMAXINFO * pMinMax = (MINMAXINFO*)lParam ;
            pMinMax->ptMinTrackSize.x = Cell_Size * 5;
            pMinMax->ptMinTrackSize.y = Cell_Size * 5;
                                                }
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);



            RECT rc;

            if (GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc)) {
                int *ptr;

                int width = rc.right - rc.left;
                int height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

                rc.left = (width - Cell_Size * 3) / 2;
                rc.top = (height - Cell_Size * 3) / 2;
                rc.right = (rc.left + Cell_Size * 3);
                rc.bottom = (rc.top + Cell_Size * 3);

                Rectangle(hdc, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);
                Rectangle(hdc, rc.left, rc.top+Cell_Size, rc.right, rc.top+Cell_Size*2);
                Rectangle(hdc, rc.left+Cell_Size, rc.top , rc.left+Cell_Size*2, rc.bottom);
                Rectangle(hdc, rc.left + Cell_Size, rc.top + Cell_Size, rc.left + Cell_Size * 2, rc.top + Cell_Size * 2);

            }



            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Or attach a console and print some numbers...

Comment: I am making this in Visual studio. so should i use windows local debugger? and also how will it help me?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your GetMousePoint. If it doesn't get there that tells you something. If the numbers are not what you expected that tells you something else. Step through the function, and the numbers will tell you more.

Comment: In `GetBoard` you are filling local variable `rc` but `pRect` is not touched, why? Then if `PtInRect` passed you are testing `rc` which has garbage values.

Comment: Just a tip for future : Add comments (in the code/ in the post) if the the code block is long. It helps a random viewer to understand your code and its functioning easily, and will fetch you more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code.

The problem is here：

[image: problem]

The easiest way is to define a global variable.

```
const int Cell_Size = 100;
RECT rc;
BOOL GetBoard(HWND hwnd, RECT *pRect)
{   
//  RECT rc;
if (GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc)) {
    int *ptr;

    int width = rc.right - rc.left;
    int height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    rc.left = (width - Cell_Size * 3) / 2;
    rc.top = (height - Cell_Size * 3) / 2;
    rc.right = (rc.left + Cell_Size * 3);
    rc.bottom = (rc.top + Cell_Size * 3);


    return TRUE;
} SetRectEmpty(pRect);
    return FALSE;

}

int GetMousePoint(HWND hwnd, int x, int y)
{
POINT pt = { x, y };

//  RECT rc;
if (GetBoard(hwnd, &rc))
{
    if (PtInRect(&rc, pt))
    {
        x = pt.x - rc.left;
        y = pt.y - rc.top;

        int column = x / Cell_Size;
        int row = y / Cell_Size;

        return column + row;
    }

}return -1;
}
```

Finally you will get the results you want：
[image: debug]